# Why do we have to get dependencies every time for Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dependencies, offline

How can we work totally offline ? Can we just download all neseccary files and update when needed or when running current app is not possible without updating ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not found a way to use flutter create while offline, you can use a created flutter project offline without any problems. You can copy another project's files to that project without being online as long as you also copy the dependencies over.